Would small integers saving gas in a struct?
I have a mapping to structs which contain multiple timestamp
struct Entry {
    uint256 createdAt;
    uint256 solvedAt;
    uint256 canceledAt;
    ...
}

mapping(address => Entry) _entries;

Apparently I only need 64 bit to store a timestamp, so I came up with the second version
struct Entry {
    uint64 createdAt;
    uint64 solvedAt;
    uint64 canceledAt;
    uint64 _padding; // make it a 256 bit int in total
    ...
}

mapping(address => Entry) _entries;

Which one is more gas efficient? The smaller integer saves storage space but requires extra code when R/W.

The second one is more cheap, the contiguous items that are less than 32 bytes are packed into a single storage slot.  You can look it up here.
